# How should I refer to a specific element in document.getComputedStyle?

Tags: javascript, html, function, position

I am making a game where there is a draggable object and I would like to store its actual place in real time. I was told I should use getComputedStyle but it only works in case I use

```
var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(document.body, null)
```

I mean if I add

```
document.write(computedStyle.marginTop)
```

it works and it writes the value of the top margin. But I need a div element's place.. I tried using

```
    var place = document.getElementById("draggable");
    var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(place, null);
    document.write(computedStyle.marginTop);
```

but it does nothing. I also tried

```
var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("draggable"), null);
```

but it also did not work.

Can somebody please help me out how should I refer to the div element with the id "draggable"?

Comment: *"but it does nothing"* It does if you have an element with the `id` `"draggable"`. If you don't, then of course it doesn't do anything. Note that `id`s and `class`es are completely different things.

Comment: *"Can somebody please help me out how should I refer to the div element with the id "draggable"?"* Works for me: http://jsbin.com/igecuSAc/1/edit

Answer (score -1):

The developer docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle seem to indicate that the following should succeed:

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById("elemId");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);
```

So, try adding `window.` to your `getComputedStyle` clause, and check that your div is named correctly.

If neither of those two things help, check your javascript console for errors.

Comment: All properties of `window` are globals, using `window` in this case is redundant (though it's best practice for clarity).